# change format of date in jquery to c# date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript code is

```
 var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 5));
```

I am getting output

```
Fri Oct 25 2013 17:15:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

The output is correct but i want output something like

25/10/2013

How can i get this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: There is a jquery library, called MomentJS, which is beautiful and can do all these kind of things.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to format the date object using the API:

```
var str = lastday.getDate() + "/" + (lastday.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + lastday.getFullYear();
```

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yeah. Fixed.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Haha, yeah, you got me! I was correct the first time ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like:

```
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 5));

var date = lastday.getDate();

// 1 is added since it's zero-based value 
// (where zero indicates the first month of the year).
var month = lastday.getMonth() + 1;      
var year = lastday.getFullYear();

// You can change the format to like 'dd/mm/yyyy' or 'mm/dd/yyyy'
// based on your requirements below
var newDate = date + '/' + month + '/' + year;


console.log(newDate); // 25/10/2013
```